# How to solve the issue of VirtualBox showing a VM with UNMOUNTABLE_BOOT_VOLUME?

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine

I downloaded some VM images for VirtualBox from

> https://dev.windows.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/tools/vms/mac/

and extracted the files, and set up a new VM on VirtualBox 5.0.12 using the extracted `.vmdk` file.  The IE 11 on Windows 7 worked fine, but since I installed something, I thought I would install another copy of the VM which is fresh, so I extracted the files again and tried to use another copy of the `.vmdk` file to set up another VM.

But VirtualBox complained that it is the same UUID and can't create another VM, so I tried instead and used the IE 10 for Win 7 image instead (not IE 11, but IE 10).

And then VirtualBox would boot up the VM and after 1.5 minutes or so, show the blue screen on the VM:

[image]

It seems like it is related to that UUID issue.  So I rebooted my Mac, and now set up a new VM using "IE 9 on Win 7", and this VM also have the same issue of `UNMOUNTABLE_BOOT_VOLUME`.  So I think somehow, VirtualBox ran into some issue and didn't set up the VM correct from this point on.  I rebooted the Mac and restarted the VM and it is the same blue screen. How can this be solved?

I also tried `chmod -R a+rw` for all the files for the extracted `.vmdk` file and for all the new files that VirtualBox created, so that all files have write permission for everybody, but that didn't solve the problem.

Answer (score 11):

I want to provide some insight as to what might be the case with `UNMOUNTABLE_BOOT_VOLUME`.

With those `.zip` files provided, if you use Mac's default zip program to unzip it (by just double clicking on the zip file on OS X El Capitan), then it will first create a `.ova` file, and then it will immediately uncompress again, to 2 files: one `.vmdk` file and one `.ovf`.

Now, you cannot use those `.vmdk` files as is.  You have to double click on `.ovf` for it to be opened by VirtualBox, and then it will clone the `.vmdk` image and make it into a VM.

I think you can also use something like the 3rd party Unarchiver, and unzip it, and it will create a `.ova` file from the `.zip` file.  In this case, also just double click it for VirtualBox to use it, and I think in this case it also would not have the `UNMOUNTABLE_BOOT_VOLUME` problem.

Comment: Using a different zip utility, Keka, helped me out

Comment: As suggested, using another unarchiving tool (The Unarchiver) fixed the problem for me.  For the larger VMs, make sure you're using a non-FAT formatted disk as well or you'll run into filesize problems.

Comment: I'm using VMWare on Windows and Windows zip program also generates an `.ovf` file, double-clicking that solves the problem for me, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Same problem, this work for me:

When you have .ovf file from VMWare, open it with any text/xml editor, and

1. replace word `ElementName` with word `Caption` in the whole file
2. replace `vmware.sata.ahci` with `AHCI`

Save and import to VirtualBox (doble click in ovf file)

Answer (score 0):

It has to do with the virtual harddisk. I've had this on a laptop which came in from a customer. Usually this means the HDD where the OS is located is pretty much dead.

You can try to use it as a slave drive on another working VM to see if it isn't corrupted and/or repair it. (In Windows you could use the disk management to open a vhd but I am not sure how this is done on mac).